# Schedule a local notification every day with phonegap cordova

Tags: cordova, notifications, phonegap-plugins, localnotification

I'm developing an app with cordova and i'm using this plugin to schedule a local notification every day to 6 o'clock
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications

Everything works fine, this is the code that i'm using to set de Notification

> ```
> /*Set 6 o'clock*/
> function setTestAlarm() {
>     var notify = new Date();
>     notify.setHours(18,00,00,00);
>
>   localNotification.add({
>         id:      1,
>         title:   'My app',
>         message: 'Hi this is a notification',
>         repeat:  'daily',
>         date:    notify,
>         autoCancel: true, 
>         ongoing: true, 
>     });
> ```

I was doing testing , and notification appears every day at 6 pm but only for 9 consecutive days and then stops appearing . What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Although its late, try the following at: https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/wiki/11.-Samples

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    text: "Good morning!",
    firstAt: tomorrow_at_6_am,
    every: "day" // "minute", "hour", "week", "month", "year"
});
```

For `tomorrow_at_6_am` you can try the following:

```
var today = new Date();
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
tomorrow.setHours(6);
tomorrow.setMinutes(0);
tomorrow.setSeconds(0);
var tomorrow_at_6_am = new Date(tomorrow);
```